# Julia language problem with assigning to an array using both subscripts and linear indexing

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

Coming from R, I'm relatively new to the Julia language.

Sometimes I come across a situation where I'd like to use two passes of indexing within the same command: first with a set of subscripts, and then with a linear index. Such as:

```
array = zeros(3, 3, 3)
array[:, :, 2][9] = 999
```

Julia responds by returning the answer, as expected:

```
julia> array[:, :, 2][9] = 999
999
```

However, the original array is unchanged:

```
julia> array[:, :, 2]
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Is this a bug, or is there some fact about the language that I'm missing, to explain why it behaves this way?

Comment: Oh, wait, you are creating a new array through slicing, the assigning 999 to element 9

Comment: Maybe ShiftedArrays can help you achieve what you want. See https://juliaarrays.github.io/ShiftedArrays.jl/latest/. Otherwise, you will have to calculate your indexes. I am new to Julia too.

Comment: The answer from mcabbott is correct but maybe a bit too technical for a new user. Just think that slicing in Julia makes a copy, so you are assigning to an other object. To avoid copying, just use `@views array[:, :, 2][9] = 999` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer

Use

```
@views array[:, :, 2][9] = 999
```

---

#### More details

The thing to know here is that `x[1] = y` is lowered to a single function call to `setindex!`, no matter what `x` is. This is a normal function, and so all of its arguments are evaluated before the function is called. Here is how you can see what is being done:

```
julia> set1(x) = x[1] = 33
set1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_lowered set1(zeros(3))
CodeInfo(
1 ─     Base.setindex!(x, 33, 1)
└──     return 33
)

julia> :( z[1,:][2] ) # the brackets show precedence, else try |> dump
:((z[1, :])[2])

julia> set2(z) = z[1,:][2] = 3^4;

julia> @code_lowered set2(zeros(2,3))
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Core.apply_type(Base.Val, 4)
│   %2 = (%1)()
│   %3 = Base.literal_pow(Main.:^, 3, %2)
│   %4 = Base.getindex(z, 1, Main.:(:))
│        Base.setindex!(%4, %3, 2)
└──      return %3
)
```

When `x` is another indexing expression, this is just the function call `getindex(z,1,:)`. That makes a copy, and `setindex!` writes into the copy, and then returns its right hand side (the temporary variable `%3`, containing `3^4`). The copy never escapes.

The way to get the behaviour you want is to make `x` a view not a copy, by writing `view(z,1,:)[2] = 33` or:

```
julia> set3(z) = @views z[1,:][2] = 33;

julia> @code_lowered set3(zeros(2,3))
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (Base.maybeview)(x, 1, Main.:(:))
│        Base.setindex!(%1, 33, 2)
└──      return 33
)

julia> z3 = zeros(2,3);

julia> set3(z3)
33

julia> z3
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  33.0  0.0
 0.0   0.0  0.0
```

It would certainly have been possible to lower `z[1,:][2] = 3` to something else, some function like `multi_setindex!(z, 3, (1,:), (2,))` perhaps. I guess that was judged to be too much complication.

I think that R has non-standard evaluation, under which a function can reach into its arguments before they are evaluated, but Julia doesn't allow this. It does have macros (always denoted with `@`) which get to act on the input syntax before evaluation. This is necessary for `@views` to work, and of course for `@code_lowered` to see something other than `33` or `9`.

Comment: Interesting, but I do agree that the `R` way of interpreting sequential subsetting is a lot more intuitive.  If I were creating `julia` I probably would have made what the OP expected the default, and required a func  `@copy`  to  do the `julia` default

Comment: Oh right, while I'm not certain whether special parsing for sequential indexing (like multi_setindex!) was ever seriously discussed, there certainly was a discussion about whether `x[1,:]` should by default make a copy or a view. At first views had their own problems, and there was talk of changing this later, and... well this didn't happen by 1.0. Most things do have lazy & eager variants, but not always equally accessible.